# How to let Intel HD Graphics go of shortcut control?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, graphics-card, keyboard-shortcuts, intel-graphics

Even if I deactivate shortcuts in Intel HD Graphics they are still blocked and can not be used in Eclipse. I can use them again, if I define a different shortcut in Intel HD Graphics.
As I don not need any shortcuts for Intel HD Graphics, I would like to just really really deactivate them globally instead of defining bogus shortcuts for it (which will interfere with other programs once I get aware of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *msconfig* or Task Manager (depending on your version of Windows) or [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to check for Intel programs and services that run at startup. On the systems I've seen with Intel Graphics, disabling *hkcmd.exe* completely disables the shortcuts.

Comment: I am using Win 8.1. But I can't find any process hkcmd.exe in task manager, no Intel Programs in Autostart. In msconfig I find under services IntelContent Protection..., and Intel HD Graphics Control Panel Service. But if I deactivate the latter, the whole program will not load. Is the program useless?

Comment: Unless you have custom brightness, colour etc. settings enabled I think it should be safe to disable the service. If you do miss anything you can always re-enable it.